# Gateway timeout issue on vercel pro hosting python app

Tags: python, deployment, vercel

I have deployed a very simple flask python app on vercel pro and it works fine until the api takes more than 15 secs.

How can I change the max duration in vercel.json file?

Tried almost every pattern nothing seems to work.

Here's the vercel.json file:

```
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "api/app.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "api/app.py"
        }
    ],
    "functions": {
        "api/app.py": {
            "maxDuration": 300
        }
    }
}
```

And the following is the app structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFRSH.png)